# How I get extension of the uploaded file in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have this row in my asp.net page:

My question is how can I get extension  of the uploaded file in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.File1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

*File1* is your *FileUpload* control. Hope this helps you!